# boost::program_options appears to cast std::array to boost::array

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-program-options, stdarray

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

#ifdef DO_BOOST_PO_TEST
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;
#endif

template <size_t I, typename T, size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<(I==N-1)>::type
array_elem_from_istream(std::istream& in, std::array<T,N>& arr) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  in.get(*ss.rdbuf(),(char)EOF);
  ss >> std::get<I>(arr);
}

template <size_t I, typename T, size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<(I<N-1)>::type
array_elem_from_istream(std::istream& in, std::array<T,N>& arr) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  in.get(*ss.rdbuf(),':');
  ss >> std::get<I>(arr);
  in.ignore(); // skip delim char
  array_elem_from_istream<I+1>(in,arr);
}

namespace std {
  template <typename T, size_t N>
  istream& operator>>(istream& in, array<T,N>& arr) {
    array_elem_from_istream<0>(in,arr);
    return in;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::array<double,3> arr;

  #ifndef DO_BOOST_PO_TEST
  std::stringstream(argv[1]) >> arr;
  #else

  try {
    po::options_description desc("Options");
    desc.add_options()
      ("arr,a", po::value(&arr), "array test");
    po::positional_options_description pos;
    pos.add("arr",1);

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
      .options(desc).positional(pos).run(), vm);
    po::notify(vm);
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  #endif

  for (auto x : arr) std::cout << x << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If compiled with

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall test.cc -o test
```

`./test '1:5:9'` prints

```
1
5
9
```

as expected. But compiling with

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -DDO_BOOST_PO_TEST test.cc -o test -lboost_program_options
```

results in an error. The most enlightening part of the error message is

```
/foo/bar/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical_streams.hpp:601:32: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ and ‘boost::array<double, 3ul>’)
```

Why in the world is it looking for `operator>>(std::istream&, boost::array<double, 3ul>&)` when it should be using `operator>>(std::istream&, std::array<double, 3ul>&)`?

If I change my `array_elem_from_istream` and `istream& operator>>` template functions' `arr` arguments to `boost:array`, but keep the `std::array<double,3> arr;` in the `main` as is, it works!

Why is `std::array<double,3>` being casted to `boost::array<double,3>` by `boost::program_options`? This is the first time I've seen `boost::program_options` change the type for which it looks for the stream operator.

Comment: 1) The error is coming from [Boost.LexicalCast](http://www.boost.org/libs/lexical_cast/), not Boost.ProgramOptions. 2) The `operator>>` overload you added for `std::array<>` is explicitly forbidden by the C++ standard. The path you've started here is a dead end.

Comment: @ildjarn, where in the standard does it say it is forbidden? I have done the same for `std::pair` and it worked perfectly fine. Do you have a suggestion about what could be gone instead? Specialize `boost::lexical_cast`?

Comment: C++11, [namespace.std]/1: "*The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified*" (and this is not one of the very few permitted exceptions. Specializing `boost::lexical_cast` would make reading into an array possible everywhere even though it only makes sense in your domain (otherwise it would be built in); so your best option is to make a UDT, which you can fully control including `operator>>`, that is implemented _in terms of_ an array type.

Comment: @ildjarn could you please post the above comment as answer, it's pretty clear that's the correct answer. Thanks